# React native Material drop down get id from json data

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, dropdown

I have used `react-native-material-dropdown` in my react native project. I am getting a data from `API`.

The issue is i am getting name successfully in drop-down but i want a `hotelId` of that selected name. I am not able to parse the whole `JSON` in the drop-down.

`JSON` :

```
    {
            "message": "Success",
            "notificationCount": 0,
            "result": [{
                "hotelId": "india3c71a2b8-05d3-476e-825a-f31e08ac3bdc",
                "name": "Hotel Samrat"
            }, {
                "hotelId": "indiae4ef0d05-f46e-48f3-9bce-a37bfde089a4",
                "name": "Hotel Kalinga Ashok"
            }],
            "status": 1,
            "totalRecord": 2,
            "scopeId": ""
   }
```

I have parsed data by :

```
var count = Object.keys(responseJSON.result).length;
            let drop_down_data = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                console.log(responseJSON.result[i].name) // I need to add 
                drop_down_data.push({ value: responseJSON.result[i].name }); // Create your array of data
            }
```

And added that array in dropdown :

```
  <Dropdown
       label={'Select hotel name'}
       data={this.state.data}
       baseColor='#79292F'
  />
```

I have gone through all stack overflow answers. but i ma not able to get the exact answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React native material dropdown pass api data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48072506/react-native-material-dropdown-pass-api-data)

Comment: @ma_dev_15 i have tried not able to get the list

Comment: So ask in that question, Also you can use valueExtractor call back to get the data

Comment: @ma_dev_15 I don't know that much of react can you please post an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass data as `{value : "", label : ""}`

```
var count = Object.keys(responseJSON.result).length;
            let drop_down_data = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                console.log(responseJSON.result[i].name) // I need to add 
                drop_down_data.push({
                value : responseJSON.result[i]. hotelId
                label: responseJSON.result[i].name 
               }); // Create your array of data
            }

//pass your drop_down data to dropdown component 
  <Dropdown
       label={'Select hotel name'}
       data={YOURFINALDATAOBJECT}
       baseColor='#79292F'
  />
```

Comment: I have one more query can you please help me? I have one more json which have name,id and price. So i want two values and one label. Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 3):

```
const drop_down_data = responseJSON.result.map(element => ({
  value: element.name,
  label: element.hotelId
}));

valueExtractor = val => {
  console.log(val);
};

<Dropdown
  label={"Select hotel name"}
  data={this.state.data}
  baseColor="#79292F"
  valueExtractor={this.valueExtractor}
/>;
```

Comment: I have one more query can you please help me? I have one more json which have name,id and price. So i want two values and one label. Any suggestion on this?

Comment: Can you please explain how i can use that. My json is {
    "message": "Success",
    "notificationCount": 0,
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "From Airport",
            "price": 200
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "From Railway Station",
            "price": 100
        }
    ],
    "status": 1,
    "totalRecord": 2,
    "scopeId": ""
}

Comment: in label you can pass JSON object with `{ id: 1, price: 2000 }`